# Why collecting Flow B inside Flow A leads to call Flow A collect block again

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two flows **FlowA and FlowB**

```
val flowA  = listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).asFlow()
val flowB  = listOf<Int>(6, 7, 8, 9, 10).asFlow()
```

When I collect **flowB** using **firstOrNull()** inside **flowA** then the collection on **flowB** leads to call **flowA** collect block i.e line number 2 again.

```
1. lifecycleScope.launch {
2.    flowA.collect {
3.        Logger.debug("${it}")
4.        Logger.debug("${flowB.firstOrNull()}")
5.    }
6. }
```

Output is perfect as it should be i.e
**1 6 2 6 3 6 4 6 5 6**
But I don't know why collecting **flowB** calls the **flowA** collect i.e line number 2 again i.e `flowA.collect` I think it should go to **line number 3** i.e
`Logger.debug("${it}")`

Comment: It shouldn't lead to calling `flowA.collect`, how do you know that it was called again? The output you provided is correct, do you see a couple of such outputs in the logs?

Comment: If you use the debugger and set a breakpoint in line 2, then note breaking there could mean two different tings: either that `collect()` was invoked or that the lambda passed to `collect()` was invoked. The latter should happen in your example, the first should not.

Comment: @broot Everything is working fine but when I attach the debugger I see the breakpoint move to line no. 2 after executing line no. 4 until the flowA is completed.

Comment: @broot But when I remove line no. 4 then flowA works as it should be i.e keep calling line no. 3 until the flowA is completed.

Comment: Yeah, so exactly as I said: breaking in the line 2 in your example most probably doesn't mean that `collect()` was executed again. It means the lambda was executed again, so this is pretty much the same as invoking line 3.

Comment: @broot Okay so it means firstOrNull is responsible for executing collect lambda again and again.
But don't know why it is doing this.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with `firstOrNull()`? Each new item of `flowA()` is collected with another invoke of lambda. How could you expect that the line 3 is executed multiple times, but the lambda that contains this line is executed only once?

Comment: Ahh, ok, you probably observed that it doesn't break if you remove `firstOrNull()`. You need to understand that the resulting bytecode may be much different than your source code, compiler uses different kind of optimizations and sometimes small change in one place affects the bytecode in another place. This is even more important with suspend functions, because they produce a very specific bytecode, execution flow could jump out of suspend functions and then jump back at a later time. With this complexity sometimes it is not that trivial to answer "what is the 16th line of code?".

Comment: So being more specific, this has nothing to do specifically with flows. You break there because there is a suspending function that returned a value. You can replace `firstOrNull()` with `coroutineScope { "AAA" }` and you'll get the same result. Explaining why exactly does it happen wouldn't be that easy. But what is the most important: your code works in almost exactly the same way in both cases. `collect()` is not being invoked multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda defines a function that you are passing to the `collect` function. The `collect` function repeatedly invokes your passed function, once for every element emitted by Flow A.

This is the same as the `forEach` function. When you pass a lambda to it, you're saying, call this function over and over for every element. `forEach` is invoked once. Internally, `forEach` invokes your passed function repeatedly.

When you set a breakpoint on this line

```
flowA.collect {
```

it is ambiguous whether you want to break on the `collect` call, or on your passed function (the lambda), so it breaks on both of them. `collect` is only called once, but your lambda-defined function is invoked repeatedly by `collect`, once for every value in the flow.

As mentioned in the comments, the code inside your lambda, such as the `firstOrNull` call, is irrelevant to the behavior of how your code inside the lambda is repeatedly invoked.